# simple calculator returning alert statments but ignoring actual functions

Tags: javascript

hey everyone im in my first semester and im pretty new to javascript. i have an assignment thats due in in a few hours and i have been racking my brain trying to figure out why my code wont display the actual function results. this is the assignment.

**Write JavaScript program which implements a fully functioning, five feature
(addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and modulo/remainder) calculator.

when i run my code it acts like i dont have any input values and returns my alert statement with a 0 or a NaN.
**MY CODE SO FAR**

```
var input1 = 0;
var input2 = 0;
var again = true;

function main()
{

    while (again === true)
    {
        inputnum1();
        inputnum2();
        operator();
    }

}
function inputnum1()
{
    var input1 = 0;


    input1 = parseInt(prompt("Input first number: ", "1"));


    while ((isNaN(input1)) || (input1 < 1))
    {
        input1 = parseInt(prompt("Numeric values starting at 1 only: " , "1"));


    }

}
function inputnum2()
{

    var input2 = 0;


    input2 = parseInt(prompt("Input second number: ", "1"));

    while ((isNaN(input2)) || (input2 < 1))
    {
        input1 = parseInt(prompt("Numeric values starting at 1 only: " , "1"));
        input2 = parseInt(prompt("Numeric values starting at 1 only: " , "1"));

    }

}

function operator()
{
    var option = 0;
    var string = "";

    string += "\nEnter 0 to terminate calculator: ";
    string += "\nEnter 1 for addition: ";
    string += "\nEnter 2 for subtraction : ";
    string += "\nEnter 3 for multiplication: ";
    string += "\nEnter 4 for division: ";
    string += "\nEnter 5 for modulo/remainder: ";

    option = parseInt(prompt(string, "1"));

    while ((isNaN(option)) || (option < 0) || (option >5))
    {
        option = parseInt(prompt(string, "1"));
    }

    chosenop(option);

}

function chosenop(option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 0:
        alert ("Terminated successfully");
        again = false;
        break;

        case 1:
        addition();

        break;

        case 2:
        subtract();
        break;

        case 3:
        multiply();
        break;

        case 4:
        divide();
        break;

        case 5:
        modulo();
        break;


    }
}

function addition()
{
    var sum = input1+input2;
    alert ("The sum is: " + sum);
}

function subtract()
{
    var diff = input1-input2;
    alert("The difference is: " + diff);

}

function multiply()
{
    var prod = input1*input2;
    alert ("The product is: " + prod);
}
function divide()
{
    var quot = (input1 + 0.0)/(input2 + 0.0);
    alert ("The quotient is: " + quot);
}
function modulo()
{
    var mod = input1%input2;
    alert ("The modulo is: " + mod);
}
main();
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and a lot of logic to go through. Have a look at the guide on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to narrow the problem if you want us to help. *"Can you complete my assignment?"* is very likely not going to get you any good answers.

Comment: thank you for the response, i do not just want the answer i having problems with my alert statements not displaying the results of the function. just  looking for a nod in the right direction. i need to lear the stuff not just get answers but ive been at it for days and thought maybe someone with experience could shout out why it was failing

Comment: whe i run it from html file and copy and paste both all math functiond retur my alert but not the actual  input 1 + input 2 results it just says "The sum is: 0"

Comment: the only meu option that works is terminate the calculator

Comment: What did the previously working version look like?  What did you add?  Or was this all coded in one sitting and your first test run failed?

Comment: i built it over the weekend  i never had a working version and this is the most i have got it to work. i basically pieced the code from the stuff he taught us in class. previously before i defined the variables as global it returned NaN ex. "The sum is: NaN" but then i define the variable globally and now instead of NaN  it says 0.  first i got the input functions and menu working but i cant seem to get the math to work. if i write it all in one function i can but the assignment says funtions for each operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'd like you to read through [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Now, to your assignment. This line in `inputnum2()`:

```
input1 = parseInt(prompt("Numeric values starting at 1 only: " , "1"));
```

is superflous.

At the beginning of your code, you have defined variables `input1` and `input2`. However, in `inputnum1()` and `inputnum2()` you do `var input1 = 0` and `var input2 = 0`, which limits their scope to the `function` block.  Here's a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope) on scope. So essentially, just remove them.

This is what your code should look like:

```
var input1 = 0;
var input2 = 0;
var again = true;

function main()
{

    while (again === true)
    {
        inputnum1();
        inputnum2();
        operator();
    }

}
function inputnum1()
{


    input1 = parseInt(prompt("Input first number: ", "1"));


    while ((isNaN(input1)) || (input1 < 1))
    {
        input1 = parseInt(prompt("Numeric values starting at 1 only: " , "1"));


    }

}
function inputnum2()
{



    input2 = parseInt(prompt("Input second number: ", "1"));

    while ((isNaN(input2)) || (input2 < 1))
    {
        input2 = parseInt(prompt("Numeric values starting at 1 only: " , "1"));

    }

}

function operator()
{
    var option = 0;
    var string = "";

    string += "\nEnter 0 to terminate calculator: ";
    string += "\nEnter 1 for addition: ";
    string += "\nEnter 2 for subtraction : ";
    string += "\nEnter 3 for multiplication: ";
    string += "\nEnter 4 for division: ";
    string += "\nEnter 5 for modulo/remainder: ";

    option = parseInt(prompt(string, "1"));

    while ((isNaN(option)) || (option < 0) || (option >5))
    {
        option = parseInt(prompt(string, "1"));
    }

    chosenop(option);

}

function chosenop(option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 0:
        alert ("Terminated successfully");
        again = false;
        break;

        case 1:
        addition();

        break;

        case 2:
        subtract();
        break;

        case 3:
        multiply();
        break;

        case 4:
        divide();
        break;

        case 5:
        modulo();
        break;


    }
}

function addition()
{
    var sum = input1+input2;
    alert ("The sum is: " + sum);
}

function subtract()
{
    var diff = input1-input2;
    alert("The difference is: " + diff);

}

function multiply()
{
    var prod = input1*input2;
    alert ("The product is: " + prod);
}
function divide()
{
    var quot = (input1 + 0.0)/(input2 + 0.0);
    alert ("The quotient is: " + quot);
}
function modulo()
{
    var mod = input1%input2;
    alert ("The modulo is: " + mod);
}
main();
```

Comment: thank you so much. i appreciate the time you took to help me out both with the rules of this forum and my homework. i thought my global variable were the problem so i kept changing them and trying it with out them and all sorts of things. i did not know that by defining var input1 = 0; in side of the function would negate the prompt input. thanks for the article as well.